# illegal reference to non-static member or unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to learn c++ with wxWidgets. Till now all my programs were written in plain C (no needs for objects), vba, bash -  as you see I'm not programer.

Even if this example is in frame of wxWidgets it's general c++ problem (actually it's mine problem with c++  ;-)

The main windows has a menu-bar with sub-menu Settings/Communication. 
I have defined a class that for a main frame in *startup.h*:

```
class startUp: public wxFrame
{    
    DECLARE_CLASS( startUp)
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
public:
    startUp();
    startUp( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = SYMBOL_....
    ~startUp();
    void OnMENUCommunicationClick( wxCommandEvent& event );
    ....
    void SetDevName(const wxString& devname);
protected:
    static wxString devName;
};
```

and *startup.cpp*:

```
....
void startUp::SetDevName(const wxString& devname) 
{
    devName=_T(devname);
}
```

The *OnMENUCommunicationClick* calls a dialog that should return the name of the device selected in wxChoice (btw, feeding of the wxChoice works). This dialog defined in another class:

```
#include "startup.h"
class Communication: public wxFrame
{  
....
void Communication::CreateControls();
protected:
    wxArrayString portChoiceStrings;
```

communication.cpp:

```
...
void Communication::CreateControls()
    std::vector<std::string> ports;
    int count = ScanSerialPorts( ports, true );
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
       portChoiceStrings.Add( wxString( ports[ i ].c_str(), wxConvUTF8 ) );
    }
    portChoice = new wxChoice( itemPanel2, ID_ComportSet, wxPoint(108, 25), wxSize(55, -1), portChoiceStrings, 0 );
    portChoice->SetSelection(0);
....
}

void Communication::OnOKClick( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    startUp::SetDevName(_T(portChoiceStrings[portChoice->GetSelection()]));
    //startUp::SetDevName(wxT(""));
    Destroy();
}
```

Now to my problem I hoped that *OnOKClick* would return to *startUp* selected device. What I've got is:
**c2352 illegal call of non-static member function**. As the member of startUp is not initialized my option was to change in *startup.h* both function and variable to static.

```
static void SetDevName(const wxString& devname);
static wxString devName;
```

The things improved - all files compile but linker says **unresolved external symbol "protected: static class wxString startUp::devName"**. Moving *devName* from protected to public doesn't change a thing.

Can somebody explain me what is "the proper" way of passing values between classes? I wouldn't like to use global variables to solve it. Apparently these are evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution.  I've removed word *static* from definitions.

In class *startup* after initialize of dialog window I've add a call to function setLink:

```
void startUp::OnMENUCommunicationClick( wxCommandEvent& event )
    {
    Communication* window = new Communication(this,ID_COMMUNICATION, _("Communication Settings"));
    window->setLink(this);
    int returnValue = window->Show();
    }
```

Than in class *Communication* I've added a link function setLink that stores pointer of main window:

```
void Communication::setLink(startUp* papi)
    {
    this->m_link = papi;
    }
```

which I could use in *OnSetClick* :

```
void Communication::OnSetClick( wxCommandEvent& event )
    {
    m_link->SetDevName(_T(portChoiceStrings[portChoice->GetSelection()]));
    Destroy();
    }
```

The m_link variable was defined in *communication.h* as a member of startUp class:

```
startUp* m_relative;
```

Everything works (*i.e.* program compiles and links without errors and the devName variable from startUp-Frame is set to value read from Communication menu.

Comment: that's one way (dialogue box pushes value before closing). if your dialogue box is non-modal, you have to have some sort of link like that. otoh if your dialogue box is modal, it might make more sense for your frame object to show it, then read the value out of it when it returns a result. both approaches work. I'd prefer to pass the link to the dialogue box's constructor, because that shows the dialogue box *needs* a link to perform properly.